# React connecting Metamask and passing signer to multiple contracts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to figure out how to share signer between multiple js files. I have a file *walletConnect.js* where I connect to Metamask and get ERC20 token contract. This works fine.

```
async function connect(){
  try{
    const accounts = await ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts",
    });
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();

    // ERC20 token contract
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(
        tokenAddress,
        tokenAbi,
        signer
     );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

and then I have another file *stake.js* where I deposit a token into a contract

```
async function stakeToken() {
   try {
     const stakingContract = new ethers.Contract(
        contractAddress,
        contractAbi,
        signer
    );
    
    // approve contract
    await tokenContract.approve(stakingContract.address, maxAmount);

    // stake tokens
    await stakingContract.stakeTokens(
      tokenContract.address,
      amount
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Everything works fine if I have all code in one file. I use useState hook and all is good. However I will have multiple staking contracts I would like to keep in separate javascript files. How do I do it when having multiple files?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to separate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a hook contracts.js like this

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

export const useContract = (address, abi) => {
  try {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);
    return contract;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return false;
  }
};
```

Now I just call useContract from any script and it returns a contract

```
const stakingContract = useContract(someAddress, someAbi);
```

this way I save a lot of redundant code